# Deployment strategy for Jetty and Scala with SBT?

Tags: java, scala, jetty, sbt

I'd like to have Jetty running on a production server and when I have a new code package to deploy I'd like to be able to do an "sbt package" to package up my code into a war file, then copy it over to the production machine's webapp folder.

Is that reasonable? If so, what is the best way to start Jetty as a daemon? Will it see the new file and automatically reload my app or do I need to restart it somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem with what you are suggesting is that **the configuration required to have the server listen or monitor the webapps folder is that there will be a production hit.**

While this type of configuration is great for development, **it isn't recommended for production applications.**

With that said, what you're looking for is a ContextDeployer, which can be configured in jetty.xml. See the Jetty documentation for your specific version of Jetty for the exact details:

```
<!-- =========================================================== -->
<!-- Configure the context deployer                              -->
<!-- A context deployer will deploy contexts described in        -->
<!-- configuration files discovered in a directory.              -->
<!-- The configuration directory can be scanned for hot          -->
<!-- deployments at the configured scanInterval.                 -->
<!--                                                             -->
<!-- This deployer is configured to deploy contexts configured   -->
<!-- in the $JETTY_HOME/contexts directory                       -->
<!--                                                             -->
<!-- =========================================================== -->
<Call name="addLifeCycle">
  <Arg>
    <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.deployer.ContextDeployer">
      <Set name="contexts"><Ref id="Contexts"/></Set>
      <Set name="configurationDir"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/contexts</Set>
      <Set name="scanInterval">5</Set>
    </New>
  </Arg>
</Call>
```

The "scanInterval" is what tells the server to monitor the contexts folder. Every 5 seconds, it checks to see if the files changed.

Finally, to start Jetty as a daemon, just use the scripts they provide you in the /bin folder:

```
./jetty.sh start
```

To stop Jetty, run:

```
./jetty.sh stop
```

And to restart Jetty, run:

```
./jetty.sh restart
```

Again, see [The Jetty Documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Jetty+Wiki) or [The Webtide Website](https://www.webtide.com/) for the exact documentation for whatever version of Jetty you're running. Different versions can differ drastically in terms of how the server is configured.

Comment: In my experience, context reloads are always memory-leaky and will eventually eat up available PermGen space in the JVM that is running Jetty.  A restart is, unfortunately, necessary, at least before memory runs out.  You can either deal with the downtime of a restart, use rolling restarts behind a load balancer, or use a solution like LiveRebel.

Comment: @brandon - Thanks for clarifying. I did mention in my answer that this isn't recommended for production, but you raise a valid point that this should perhaps be highlighted further. Will update my answer.

Comment: +1 for load balancer, preserve performance and uptime, win-win

Comment: @virtualeyes - Thanks for the feedback. Not to appear small :), but did you mean to upvote this? I saw the +1 comment but no upvote in my reputation history. I did not see an upvote when you left your comment earlier, so am not sure if the one there is you or someone else. :)  No pressure, just following up :)  Thanks again!

Comment: @jmort253 hey, sorry, the upvote mentioned was for brandon's comment re: the load balancer point specifically

Comment: @virtualeyes - Ok, no worries. I thought that was odd because I didn't mention load balancing :)  Thanks for clarifying + following up.